# Would a progamming language in lojban mean that a program could be written in a natural language?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics, lojban

Imagine a new computer programming language whose keywords and all other syntax were in lojban (or equivalent language - will explain in a bit). Allowing lojban to be a "natural" language itself, would the resulting programmes appear to be natural language?

This is my reasoning:

Since all lojban  can be expressed in predicate logic (I believe), and all computer programmes can be expressed in predicate logic. Then there could be an isomorphism between lojban and computer programs. So every computer programme could be expressed in lojban, which to a native speaker would appear natural.

Comment: Nobody allows Lojban to be a natural language, with or without quotes. There is no Lojban speech community. Programming, on the other hand, is something that Lojban is reasonably well adapted to, so you could say it was a programming language inside another programming language, like awk and sed inside bash.

Comment: Every computer program can be expressed in any human language (natural or constructed). The problem is the other direction - interpreting human language algorithmically (because of ambiguity ).

Comment: @Atamiri, so considering that opposite direction. Can every valid lojban sentence be mapped to a programme? And if such a lojban -> programme interpreter existed would then the learning of lojban mean that you could learn a new language and a programming language in one fell swoop?

Comment: The famous book "Aṣṭādhyāyī" by the great Indian grammarian [Pāṇini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81%E1%B9%87ini) (5th-4th century BC), which is a grammar of Sanskrit, is actually a pogram for human brain, with data arrays, procedures and functions, arranged in code lines and written in a programming language specially devised by Pāṇini for this purpose. To load the program into the human memory, one has to memorise about 10,000 lines of code, in verses. When the program is being executed by a human brain, the person just speaks Sanskrit, that's the purpose of it.

Comment: Actually, Aṣṭādhyāyī is an example of grammaticasl system alternative to that of Europe (e.g. Aritstotelian), but it would be too a far-fetched assumption to call it 'a programming language', because cognitive systems could not and cannot determine one's thinking.

Comment: I don't think it would mean that. Programs are mostly longer than one sentence. Given a felicitous text, one could convert it into logical forms which in turn could be interpreted algorithmically. But programming languages have conventions and restrictions so the closest you'd get is a declarative "program" similar to theories in logic programing. It's all about interpretation.

Comment: @jlawler: There *is* a [lojban speech community](http://www.lojban.org/tiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions%20About%20Lojban#G4).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a hypothetical question about computer programming languages and a constructed language with no objective answer. Quora welcomes questions with no "one right answer" though, so maybe try it there.

Comment: This question does not appear to be off-topic (at least not to my mind) because it deals with linguistic modelling, constructed languages and computer linguistics.

Comment: @Manjusri: Even if you disagree about the scope, that's only one problem. The other being that it's subjective, doesn't have "one right answer", will only attract opinion and debate etc.

Comment: I believe this question would be more apt in StackOverflow than here - relationship to linguistics per-se is very tenous. Though I believe it does have an answer: OP seems to believe 1) the difficulty in reading programs is due to their being written in artificial, cut-down versions of natural languages, and 2) should a program be written in a natural language, it'd be easier to understand by a native speaker. Both are false, and for very good reasons. Relationship to predicate logic doesn't really matter, for a program can be in a number of paradigms, some more suitable for some langs.

Comment: @hippietrail: there is no clear line separating programming languages and human languages, constructed or not. There are plenty of other examples that are on, what you might consider, the separator. And the question of where there is an isomorphism is not subjective. Either there is, or there isn't.

Comment: There is a very clear line. Programming languages only have declaration and/or imperative. There is no equivalent of past tense, subjunctive, etc ad infinitum. What is the equivalen of a conversation in assembly, C++, FORTRAN, Java, PHP, etc?

Comment: Lisp is all questions, and SNOBOL is all string searches. There are other types beside declaration and imperative. Still, to say that Lojban has a speech community is silly. Nobody habitually speaks Lojban, and certainly there are no native speakers brought up from childhood speaking it. There is a community of Lojban enthusiasts, but no **speech** community.

Comment: @hippietrail: Prolog is all facts and queries. Event semantics takes care of tense, possible-world semantics addresses subjunctives, both, usually represented in FOL. Some other commenters have written examples of that right here, on Ling.SE. [These guys](http://inform7.com/learn/movies/) program games in English. Really, the field is too vast. I could go on!

Comment: Programming languages can be mapped to a *subset* of a natural language. It has been asserted that there is "no clear line separating programming languages and human languages". To prove that we would also require some examples of the reverse: arbitrary natural language being transformed into programming language. Perhaps the opening of Nabokov's *Lolita*?

Comment: @hippietrail: "To prove that we would also require some examples of the reverse"... I don't see why. And natural languages don't need to be arbitrary. If one were to talk like opening of *Lolita* when called to a witness stand, one would be booked for contempt of court.

Comment: "I don't see why". Because natural language is bigger than programming languages. The former can do things the latter cannot do. Showing that human can act like a chicken is very different from showing that a chicken can act like a man. Your examples only show that a man can act like a chicken.

Comment: @hippietrail: there are literate native speakers of English who cannot make out head or tail of Shakespeare. Why expect a computer program to do so? Don't tell the computer irrelevant things. Then there are garden path sentences that most humans would swear are wrong, and yet computer programs can parse correctly.

Comment: Non sequitor. Parsing is nothing to do with "no clear line separating programming languages and human languages". Parsing is what a program might do, a programming language is what a program is written in.

Comment: There is no way for a computer to analyze a program except by parsing it. This is true even for programs written in English, which I linked to earlier.

Comment: I'm new to Stack Exchange, and I don't really understand if this level of debate is normal. Should I post my question on Stack Overflow, or fight for its existence here? Can I do both?

Comment: @notconfusing : no, it's not normal. Actually, Stack Exchange "discourages" discussions, trying to emphasize giving factual answers that can be semi-objectively evaluated as to their truthfulness. This question, though, is one of those that show everyone's opinions on a subject. Don't worry, an admin can move your question to Stack Overflow if deemed necessary, or you can ask them to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few corrections: lojban, though a human language, is not a natural language; it is a conlang. AFAIK, there are no native speakers of lojban: that would require teaching lojban as one of the primary languages to a very young child.

Lojban is syntactically unambiguous, and only mostly unambiguous semantically. If there were a lojban programming language, this should not matter because one would avoid writing semantically ambiguous forms (like metaphors). This question has come up on various forums for lojban, Prolog, Haskell, etc., The consensus on those forums seems to be that it is possible, but no one has done it yet. Some people ([e.g. 1](http://web.mit.edu/~rspeer/Public/jimpe.pdf), [e.g. 2](http://gulik.pbworks.com/w/page/7760016/Lojban%20programming%20language)) have attempted to implement  such a thing, but AFAIK, for very limited domains.

Comment: lojysamban: Prolog with lojban — https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lojysamban